# Merging results from two queries in a long table with a measure type

Tags: select, sparql, opendata

## Background

The queries below source some publicly available unemployment data from [statistics.gov.scot](https://statistics.gov.scot/home) portal. Most of the data expressed on that portal is available as count or ratio. I've a set of two queries that I can use to derive ratio or count using the following:

- Ratio

  ```
  ?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/ratio> ?val_rto .
  ```
- Count

  ```
  ?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/count> ?val_cnt .
  ```

I would like to combine those queries so I can get both measures (ratio and count) in one table.

```
------------------------------------------------
| geo         | time      | measure | value   | 
===============================================
| "S01002267" | "2001-Q2" | "Ratio" | 0.989808|
| "S01002266" | "2001-Q2" | "Ratio" | 0.989878|
| "S01002267" | "2001-Q2" | "Count" | 11111111|
| "S01002266" | "2001-Q2" | "Count" | 222     | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

In a word, I want to have an actual value in one column and label for value type (measure, ratio, something else) in another column. I'm getting stuck at last step where I can get *either* count or ratio.

### Endpoint

Web interface for the endpoint is available at: https://statistics.gov.scot/sparql

---

## Queries

### Ratio

```
# Prefixes
# As derived from https://statistics.gov.scot/sparql
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX sdmx: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/concept#>
# Added for convenience 
PREFIX dim: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/dimension#>

# Query
SELECT DISTINCT ?geo ?time ?measure ?val_cnt ?val_rto
WHERE {
    ?x dim:refArea ?geoURI .
    ?geoURI rdfs:label ?geo .


    ?x qb:dataSet <http://statistics.gov.scot/data/job-seekers-allowance> .

    ?x dim:refPeriod ?periodURI .
    ?periodURI rdfs:label ?time .

    ?x qb:measureType ?measureURI .
    ?measureURI rdfs:label ?measure .

    ?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/ratio> ?val_rto .

    FILTER (?time IN ("2001-Q1", "2001-Q2"))
}
LIMIT 20
```

#### Results

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| geo         | time      | measure | val_cnt | val_rto  |
==========================================================
| "S01002267" | "2001-Q2" | "Ratio" | ""      | "4.1E0"  |
| "S01002266" | "2001-Q2" | "Ratio" | ""      | "1.6E0"  |
| "S01002269" | "2001-Q2" | "Ratio" | ""      | "0"      |
| ...         | ...       | ...     | ...     | ...      |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

### Count

```
# Prefixes
# As derived from https://statistics.gov.scot/sparql
PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX sdmx: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/concept#>
# Added for convenience 
PREFIX dim: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/dimension#>

# Query
SELECT DISTINCT ?geo ?time ?measure ?val_cnt ?val_rto
WHERE {
    ?x dim:refArea ?geoURI .
    ?geoURI rdfs:label ?geo .


    ?x qb:dataSet <http://statistics.gov.scot/data/job-seekers-allowance> .

    ?x dim:refPeriod ?periodURI .
    ?periodURI rdfs:label ?time .

    ?x qb:measureType ?measureURI .
    ?measureURI rdfs:label ?measure .

    ?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/count> ?val_cnt .

    FILTER (?time IN ("2001-Q1", "2001-Q2"))
}
LIMIT 20
```

#### Results

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| geo                 | time      | measure | val_cnt | val_rto |
=================================================================
| "Comrie West"       | "2001-Q2" | "Count" | "0"     | ""      |
| "Comrie West"       | "2001-Q2" | "Count" | "10"    | ""      |
| "Comrie West"       | "2001-Q2" | "Count" | "5"     | ""      |
| ...                 | ...       | ...     | ...     | ...     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: just use one of your queries and in the query body the `SELECT DISTINCT ?geo ?time ?measure ?value
WHERE { ... ?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/count> ?value .}
  UNION {?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/ratio> ?value} ... } LIMIT 20`

Comment: Alternative is a property path, i.e. `?x <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/count>|<http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/ratio> ?value`

Comment: In general, more compact form of your query: `PREFIX qb: <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dim: <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/dimension#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?geo ?time ?measure ?value WHERE {VALUES ?time {"2001-Q1" "2001-Q2"} ?x dim:refArea/rdfs:label ?geo;qb:dataSet <http://statistics.gov.scot/data/job-seekers-allowance> ; dim:refPeriod/rdfs:label ?time ; qb:measureType/rdfs:label ?measure ; <http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/count>|<http://statistics.gov.scot/def/measure-properties/ratio> ?value} LIMIT 20`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks, feel freedom to make it an answer.